# How will cut options -b and -c become different with Internationalization

Tags: bash, cut

```
`-b BYTE-LIST'
`--bytes=BYTE-LIST'
     Select for printing only the bytes in positions listed in
     BYTE-LIST.  Tabs and backspaces are treated like any other
     character; they take up 1 byte.  If an output delimiter is
     specified, (see the description of `--output-delimiter'), then
     output that string between ranges of selected bytes.

`-c CHARACTER-LIST'
`--characters=CHARACTER-LIST'
     Select for printing only the characters in positions listed in
     CHARACTER-LIST.  The same as `-b' for now, but
     internationalization will change that.  Tabs and backspaces are
     treated like any other character; they take up 1 character.  If an
     output delimiter is specified, (see the description of
     `--output-delimiter'), then output that string between ranges of
     selected bytes.
```

Description for `-c` says that : **The same as `-b' for now, but internationalization will change that.**

I am assuming Internationalized characters for some languages could have multi-byte characters and that is when `-c` and `-b` will behave differently..correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Let's do a test:

```
$ cat a
200
bést
203
-Ümlaut
$ cut -b2-3 a
00
é           <---- é has 2 bytes
03
Ü           <---- Ü has 2 bytes
$ cut -c2-3 a
00
és
03
Üm
```

Comment: This makes total sense to me. What does not is that for me on Ubuntu 04.12 (UTF-8: "en_US.UTF-8") both 'cut -c2-3 a' and 'cut -b2-3 a' yield the same result - that of 'cut -b2-3 a'.

Comment: @Ronald interesting... I just tried in cygwin 8.15-1 with `cut (GNU coreutils) 8.15` and it also shows the same for either `cut -b2-3 a` and `cut -c2-3 a`. It definitelly has to be with the locale and cut version.