# Byte count in file unix per line

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I want to count all lines in a file with byte count in line greater than a value (say 10). How can I do so?

I tried using `cat file | awk'length($0)>10'` but this is giving me all lines with char count greater than 10. I want to count bytes in line.

I wrote the below code but it is not working. It returns some gibberish output:

```
#!/bin/ksh
file="a.txt"
while read line
do
    a=`wc -c "${line}"|awk {'print $1'}`
    if [ $a -ne 493]; then
    echo "${line}"
    fi
done <"$file"
```

Comment: You may want `wc -c` for bytes.

Comment: This would give me count for whole file. I want lines with byte count greater than a given value

Comment: You can read line by line and then `echo "$line" | wc -w`, etc.

Comment: How are you differentiating what is a "byte" vs. what is a "char"? Unless you're using a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8, they're likely the same...

Comment: @twalberg in general it does not make a difference, but it can in some cases. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800440/byte-count-in-file-unix-per-line/27800788#comment44014226_27800788) below my answer. Also see [How will cut options -b and -c become different with Internationalization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25619162/1983854).

Comment: @fedorqui I understand that there is sometimes a difference. I guess I worded that poorly - what I was trying to get at is which particular mapping of bytes (a.k.a. encoding) is in use here. For some (less frequently encountered) encodings, finding the proper tool for this may not be so simple, while it's probably doable with the more common UTF-* and/or ISO 8859-* and a few others...

Comment: @twalberg I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is quite good, only that you have to do `a=$(wc -c <<< "$line")` or `a=$(echo "$line" | wc -w)`, no need to pipe to `awk`. Also, note need an extra space after `493` in the `if` condition.

All together:

```
#!/bin/ksh
file="a.txt"
while read line
do
    a=$( echo -n "$line" | wc -c) # echo -n to prevent counting new line
    if [ "$a" -ne 493 ]; then
      echo "${line}"
    fi
done <"$file"
```

Comment: Can you please change file name to a.txt. I your answer

Comment: If you use `bash` you can get the length with `a=${#line}`

Comment: @MarkSetchell true, only that the OP wants the length in bytes, not chars, and I guess `${#var}` returns chars. If we say `r="hàllo"` (an accent there), then `echo ${#r}` returns 5, whereas `echo "hàllo" | wc -c` returns 7. // If we say `r="hallo"` (no accents), `echo ${#r}` returns 5, whereas `echo "hallo" | wc -c` returns 6.

Comment: You'll want to `echo -n` to prevent the newline from being included in the count.